# Extract application properties without controlling loading of properties files

Tags: java, spring, properties

I'm looking for a way to extract *application properties*. Most thread I found on this topic suggest inheriting `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. But that is not an option as the loading of properties is done outside the application in a third party framework. Is there an other way to get the properties that does not involve overridden `spring` methods?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use jndi with spring application parameters?
For instance -> 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mock-objects-jndi